# Getting java.net.UnknownHostException while executing the basic automation script for Rest Api

Tags: java, automation, web-api-testing

I just executed the below script :

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
public class Basics {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
  RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";
  given().
  param("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
  param("radius","500").
  param("types","food").
  param("key","AIzaSyDXR2YGnRu3-112ttezUsQ-T2zOkb6aafE").
  when().
  get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);  
 }
}
```

But I am getting an exception while running the script.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
```

Could someone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: do you have an internet connection? are you using a proxy or filter or firewall etc?

Comment: An `UnknownHostException` means that your machine cannot resolve the given hostname, `maps.googleapis.com`, to an IP address. More likely than not, it's a DNS problem. Can you do an `nslookup maps.googleapis.com` from the machine on which the application runs? This is not necessarily the machine on which you are developing.

Comment: @SteelToe Yes I am working in my office machine. Proxy or filter exits

Comment: @SeverityOne I just  checked nslookup maps.googleapis.com and I could see Server:  questgedctvm.com
Address:  10.197.72.16
Name:    maps.googleapis.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a problem with your DNS. If you do `nslookup maps.googleapis.com`, you should see more or less the following:

```
Server:  questgedctvm.com
Address:  10.197.72.16 

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    googleapis.l.google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4002:805::200a
          216.58.205.74
          216.58.205.106
          216.58.205.138
          216.58.205.170
          216.58.205.202
          216.58.198.10
          216.58.198.42
          172.217.23.106
          216.58.205.42
Aliases:  maps.googleapis.com
```

If this is not what you're seeing (the actual IP addresses may differ, but you should get a bunch) then you have a DNS issue that you need to solve. It's not a Java issue.

Comment: Agree. When I checked with postman tool, it is giving 200 ok status. for this url

Comment: I forgot i was deploying to a DMZ associated app, and this was technically my issue, since you have to manually map the DNS to the IP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get the response from host `https://maps.googleapis.com` through your 
code.

you can launch a UNIX terminal and use the nslookup command (among others) to see if your DNS server can resolve the host name to an IP address successfully.

try `$  nslookup https://maps.googleapis.com`

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
RequestSpecification httpRequest = given();

Response response = httpRequest.
        param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362").
        param("radius", "500").
        param("types", "food").
        param("key", "AIzaSyDXR2YGnRu3-112ttezUsQ-T2zOkb6aafE").
        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"); 

System.out.println("Response Body is =>  " + response.asString());
```

**Update**

```
$ nslookup https://maps.googleapis.com

Server: questgedctvm.com
Address: 10.197.72.16

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    googleapis.l.google.com
Addresses: <IP_Addresses>

Aliases:  https://maps.googleapis.com
```

check the IP_Address, if you are able to get the IP_Address for host `https://maps.googleapis.com` than everything is Okay. You can try my code and check the coming response.

Comment: Server: questgedctvm.com Address: 10.197.72.16 Name: maps.googleapis.com

Comment: I have executed your script, but the result is same. Getting the same exception

Comment: are you able to get the host IP_Address (this one is different from DNS server IP)?