# Not able to retrieve response for a GET request via Karate

Tags: karate

I am getting an error as below when I execute my scenario

**Feature**: sample karate test script for ws+

**Background**:

- url 'https://pluss-nav2.ekstern.acos/api/api/register/'
- configure headers = { Accept: 'application/json' }
- configure ssl = true
- header Authorization = 'Bearer token'

**Scenario**: get all users and then get the first user by id

Given path 'sakmaler'

- When method get
- Then status 200

When method gets executed, I get the below exception.

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException:
>
> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: wsplussnav.feature:14 -
>
> java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (pluss-nav2.ekstern.acos)

**Note**: I get this exception only when I execute test on this url. This url does not have any proper domain like .net or .com

I tested in postman, and it works.

I tested in powershell command, and it works.

Any idea how to re-solve this error in Karate?

Comment: Is the URL correct? .../api/api/...? does the same karate code work with the public url?

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct. If I change to public URL, it works. The issue is only with this URL

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are behind a corporate proxy, which is why it works in P*stman.

Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

```
karate.configure('proxy','http://myhost:80');
```

EDIT: for others landing here, besides the fact that an HTTP proxy may be in the picture - another place where Karate behaves a bit differently than Postman is that Karate [does not auto-send an `Accept` header by default](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/388#issuecomment-386845749).

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I spoke with IT, and we do not have any proxy setting. I am executing the test inside our corporate network.

Comment: @Senthil you have some DNS issue. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644598/143475 - if you can replicate this on a public host (highly unlikely :) we will look at the issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I have changed the headers to                                         
    * url 'https://pluss-nav2.ekstern.acos/api/api/register/'
 * configure headers = { Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' }
 * configure ssl = { trustAll: true };
  * header Authorization = 'Bearer token'                                                                                                
  After changing this, It throws different exception     com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: wspluss.feature:14 - 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Also, I tried the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198787/karate-connection-reset-error-when-connecting-to-internal-qa-server-dev-server but it did not help