# POST request is not working in Karate but same API call is working fine through Postman

Tags: rest, automation, postman, karate

I'm hitting one post API call with below JSON, it's throwing 'Invalid Request' error when I run through karate API automation, but when I hit the same API call in post man it's working fine without any errors

```json
{
    "title": "automation",
    "titleImage": {
        "url": "https://qastatic.hopscotch.in/fstatic/boutique/banner/202310/5141ea6e-4f20-4930-8fd8-a810ab1d0a3c_full.jpg?version=1696382122533",
        "height": 296,
        "width": 296
    },
    "carouselType": "1",
    "sorts": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "value": "All"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "Boy 1-5 years"
        }
    ],
    "position": "6",
    "platform": [
        "IOS",
        "ANDROID",
        "MWEB"
    ],
    "startDate": "2023-10-04T06:42:29",
    "endDate": "2026-10-08T06:42:00",
    "tiles": [
        {
            "type": "plp",
            "position": 1,
            "imageUrl": "https://qastatic.hopscotch.in/fstatic/boutique/banner/202310/1320e159-2c49-4bc5-9dba-8b41bb921582_full.jpg?version=1696382140898",
            "actionId": 11896,
            "actionName": "PLP-Collectiona - 11896"
        },
        {
            "type": "plp",
            "position": 2,
            "imageUrl": "https://qastatic.hopscotch.in/fstatic/boutique/banner/202310/9cb9d627-e45e-4a72-aed1-4b213721700a_full.jpg?version=1696382158006",
            "actionId": 11895,
            "actionName": "testPLP29-09-2023 - 11895"
        },
        {
            "type": "plp",
            "position": 3,
            "imageUrl": "https://qastatic.hopscotch.in/fstatic/boutique/banner/202310/f4f5d594-7a30-4425-973f-e918b594107b_full.jpg?version=1696382172121",
            "actionId": 11892,
            "actionName": "EDD filter test - 11892"
        }
    ],
    "userTypes": [
        "GU",
        "RB",
        "NB",
        "PU"
    ],
    "customerIds": "",
    "navigation": false,
    "tileHeight": 296,
    "tileWidth": 296
}
```

```
Headers {content-type : 'application/json', cookie:#(updatedCookie)}
```

Solutions I have tried:

1.Verified if the JSON is in correct format or not
2.Tried removing extra spaces

but none of them are working!

Can you please suggest solution for this?

Comment: see if this post helps (see second link) else, sorry - it is very hard to troubleshoot otherwise. you can export a cURL command from postman and study it to see what magic it is doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60055179/143475

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the requests from Postman and Karate are different (even if you've already checked the body). You can look at the requests in detail (including headers), e.g. via [Reponsler](https://www.responsler.com). Just choose a hostname and send there once from Postman and once from Karate. Then compare both requests. I'm sure you will find differences, which you can then eliminate.